# How are input fields values passed to php

Tags: php, html

I have a database and a login form and want to write a php script that validates the login.

How are the  types' data access and used?

For example, how do I access the input entered from the user in these elements.

```
<p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
<p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
```

I want to use the login and password for validation. How can these be passed to a php script?

EDIT: I set the action to

```
<form method="post" action="loginVerification.php">
```

and when I enter the fields and submit the values, my OS wants to save the loginVerification.php. When I save it I dont get the echo.

I have this in the php file

```
<?php
 echo $_POST['login'];
 echo $_POST['password'];
```

How do I write the logs to a file in php, or is there a way to do runtime verification for php?

Edit 2:

```
  <div class="container">
<section class="login">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form method="post" action="loginVerification.php">
    <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p class="remember_me">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
        Remember me on this computer
      </label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
</section>

<section class="login-help">
  <p>Lost password? <a href="index.html">Click here to reset it</a>.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Since you have stated that "my OS wants to save the loginVerification.php. When I save it I dont get the echo" Are you running any HTTP server with PHP mod ? what URL are you using to access the login page ?

Comment: Im really confused for some reason. I am running MAMP and have files in the htdocs folder. When this form gets submitted, the php wants to download. How do I retrieve or see the echo statements of the recieved values. or is this php file download triggered before the echo $_POST executes?

Comment: "The php wants to download" means that the HTTP server is not running or PHP is not enabled. Are you accessing the page by using a URL like http://localhost/login.php or http://localhost/login.html or on MAC http://localhost/~username/login.html ? Go into MAMP settings and check whether PHP is enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I will check. So if php was on what would happen? Where would I see the echos?

Comment: Once the PHP is on the echos will be displayed in the browser itself, you will get transferred to loginVerification.php page.

Comment: I thought php was turned on by default with MAMP. How can I check it or turn it on? Thanks

Comment: Provide me the URL by which you are accessing the page. I have not used MAMP, I use LAMP. It is enabled by default, check whether the HTTP server is running.

Comment: if I access the page directly in the browser with the path, the file downloads. If I submit the form that uses <form method="post" action="loginVerification.php"> the file also wants to download. php should be on. The apache server is running too.

Comment: file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testapp/loginVerification.php

Comment: oh, was messing around by trying to run it from the index.html filepath in the browser. :/

Comment: Try using `http://localhost/~username/testapp/page.php` or `http://localhost/testapp/page.php` to access the pages.

Answer (score 1):

If your form method is `post`, these variables would be accessible through `$_POST['login']` and `$_POST['password']`.

Answer (score 1):

These fields should be part of a `<form>` element, such as the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
  <!-- input elements here -->
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Submitting the form will pass your data to your `action` location. In this case, to a script on the server called "process.php". Assuming your `method` is `POST`, from within process.php you could access your input fields via the `$_POST` global array:

```
<?php

  // Show value of <input type="text" name="foo" />
  echo $_POST['foo'];

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. So those string literals for the elements could name clash with e.g. post elements coming in from a mobile app?

Comment: @Helium3 I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Helium3 no they are one in the same. That is how they are referenced.

Comment: @Helium3 Ah, I see what you're asking. `$_POST['foo']` is the representation of `<input name='foo' />` on the server-end. When that HTML element gets submitted via `POST`, it is  handled on the other end from within the `$_POST` array, under a key that corresponds to the name of the element as it existed in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get the data from HTML forms :

- **POST**

HTML form tag :

```
<form method="post" action="some.php">
<input type="text" name="username" size="20"/>
<input type="password" name="password" size="20"/>
</form>
```

To access the values of fiedls in some.php you can use the `$_POST` super global.
eg: `$_POST['username']`

- **GET**

HTML form tag :

```
<form method="get" action="some.php">
<input type="text" name="username" size="20"/>
<input type="password" name="password" size="20"/>
</form>
```

To access the values of fiedls in some.php you can use the `$_GET` super global.
eg: `$_GET['username']`

Now to create a login system you need to create a database of username and password :

```
username | password
----------------------
abc      | passcode!@#
xyz      | passco#$%^^
```

For signing-in you can use session to keep the user logged in across several pages (web application). In the login script check whether the user is valid by looking into the table and set some value for a session's variable using the `$_SESSION` super global. You can access that variable in any page of your web application, for that the session needs to be started in every page using :

```
session_start()
```

function. On each and every page, the session's variable must be checked for its value, if it is valid show the page else land the user to the login page.

Here you can find information on sessions : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Form input values are passed via POST *typically*. From your PHP, you access those values using the `$_POST` superglobal like this:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

The array key in the $_POST array is what you set **name** to in your HTML element like `name="login"`.

When using this value, be aware that it comes straight from your user and **should not** be trusted. If you don't filter it prior to using it with database operations, you run the very real risk of becoming a victim of SQL injection leading to your site being compromised.

Comment: Hi. thanks. So how are these php triggers debugged live? If I enter the values in the input fields as the user would. How can I see the script executing, such as runtime verification? Also, regarding the injection, I am new to php, but is there a bind method for login forms similar to the mysql bind in php?

Comment: Debugging a form submission live wouldn't really be of much use as it happens so fast. You can use tools like FireBug in your browser to see what the request looks like including what data was passed and returned. The form is simply for passing values to your PHP script. At that point you use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

in your php file try this

```
echo $_REQUEST['login'];
echo $_REQUEST['password'];
```

Comment: Much better to use POST or GET rather than REQUEST

Comment: @Anigel Defend that statement.

Comment: agree the form type is not displayed in the question that is why i used REQUEST

Comment: @Anigel That's just for security. If security isn't an issue, does your statement still stand? Just playing devil's advocate, I always use POST/GET.

Comment: @Blake you make it sounds like security it never important,  Regardless of that it is always best practice to know where your data is coming from and how it was submitted. if you are only expecting input from a POSTed form, please explain why you would be happy to take input from a cookie or a url parameter?

Comment: @Anigel I didn't say security is not important, but the method is never mentioned by the OP. As well, not every variable needs to be "secure" or even validated, especially if it never touches anything else.

Comment: @Anigel: That's a questionable advise. The article alludes to stale cookie values. (Nevermind this not be the case since 5.3 anymore). The super vague description as security issue isn't helpful, as it's primarly an application logic gotcha. Cookie binding != cookie injection. (I realize this cursorily assesment is handed around on SO. Might be time to rationalize this a bit.)

Comment: @mario, as I said above, if you are only expecting input from a POSTed form, please explain why you would be happy to take input from a cookie or a url parameter?

Comment: @Anigel I could think of a few examples, one of which being a "referral" system, where you don't care if the userid is received via post on the form, or a get as a referral link.

Comment: i love when questions trigger these.

Comment: @Anigel: If that's the case, then it's indeed pointless to query divergent data sources. In this specific case it might even be sensible to restrain it. However generally speaking, limiting input to one source isn't. Both transfer schemes are functionaly equivalent. It's just the people wrongly presume POST to be "more secure" or e.g. "caching resistant" (same can be accomplished for GET with proper headers). The core idea of having a source agnostic $_REQUEST array isn't a bad one, in particular if you are alternating between form requests and e.g. AJAX. (Which I'd imagine for the login thing